# How to implement logwatch functionality on top of systemd journal?

Tags: security, systemd, syslog, error-handling

Logwatch scans logfiles with regular intervals, collects errors and stuff, then mails it to the admin. This was back in syslog and logfiles days. What's the corresponding solution for systemd's journal?

Comment: You could make the modifications to logwatch. Searching I found no official support for it, and no forks. There are some modifications that were made to the fedora package around systemd.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the blog post by @Siosm I created a tool with which you can write a simple config with patterns, and then you get notified about everything not matching these patterns: journalwatch.

You can find more in the [Archlinux Forum Thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1434882).

It seems there's also a [patch and a hack](http://sourceforge.net/p/logwatch/patches/34/) available in the logwatch tracker by now.

Answer (score 3):

I use journal-brief as a replacement for logwatch, thought it doesn't work quite the same way.

https://libraries.io/pypi/journal-brief

Answer (score 3):

Since this question is so old, though, I suppose the current answer should be that logwatch now supports systemd-journal, so, the question is no longer accurate.  (I don't know when this feature was added, but at least as early as version 7.4.3 from what I can tell.)

Comment: Nice! Mind editing and pointing out which logwatch version started support?

Comment: Full disclosure, I don't use logwatch (any more), so I'm not reporting first hand experience.  Also, it is not straightforward, as this capability is not prominently advertised on official project pages.

Comment: Did some digging and seems logwatch did support systemd/journald since 2017. Problem is there seems to be no detail/accurate documentation on how to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no replacement for logwatch functionality as of today. However, it is quite easy for someone to make it's own using the [systemd.journal python module](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html).

I wrote a [blog post with an example](https://tim.siosm.fr/blog/2014/02/24/journald-log-scanner-python/) a couple months ago.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from systemd import journal
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import re
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# First, let's define patterns to ignore.

# Those are for matching dynamically named units:
session = re.compile("session-[a-z]?\d+.scope")
sshUnit = re.compile("sshd@[0-9a-f.:]*")

# Those will match the logged message itself:
sshSocketStart = re.compile("(Strating|Stopping) OpenSSH Per-Connection Daemon.*")
sshAcceptPublicKey = re.compile("Accepted publickey for (bob|alice).*")
sshReceivedDisconnect = re.compile("Received disconnect from.*")
logindNewSession = re.compile("New session [a-z]?\d+ of user (bob|alice).*")
sshdSessionClosed = re.compile(".*session closed for user (bob|alice).*")
sessionOpenedRoot = re.compile(".*session opened for user root.*")
suSessionClosedGit = re.compile(".*session opened for user git.*")
anacronNormalExit = re.compile("Normal exit (\d+ jobs run).*")
postfixStatistics = re.compile("statistics:.*")
postfixHostnameDoesNotResolve = re.compile("warning: hostname .* does not resolve to address .*: Name or service not known")

# Open the journal for reading, set log level and go back one day and 10 minutes
j = journal.Reader()
j.log_level(journal.LOG_INFO)
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1, minutes=10)
j.seek_realtime(yesterday)

# We'll store messages in this variable
mailContent = []

# Filter and store output
for entry in j:
    # Special cases for logs without a message
    if 'MESSAGE' not in entry:
        mailContent.append( 'U %s %s[%s]: EMPTY!' % (
            datetime.ctime(entry['__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP']),
            entry['PRIORITY'],
            entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'],
        ))

    # With systemd unit name
    elif '_SYSTEMD_UNIT' in entry:
        if entry['PRIORITY'] > 4:
            if entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT'] == "wtcomments.service":
                pass
            elif entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT'] == "ffsync.service":
                pass
        elif session.match(entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT']):
            pass
        elif sshUnit.match(entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT']):
            if sshAcceptPublicKey.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
                pass
            elif sshReceivedDisconnect.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
                pass
        elif entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT'] == "systemd-logind.service":
            if logindNewSession.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
                pass
        elif entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT'] == "postfix.service":
            if postfixHostnameDoesNotResolve.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
                pass
        else:
            mailContent.append( 'U %s %s %s %s[%s]: %s' % (
                datetime.ctime(entry['__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP']),
                entry['PRIORITY'],
                entry['_SYSTEMD_UNIT'],
                entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'],
                entry['_PID'],
                entry['MESSAGE']
            ))

    # With syslog identifier only
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "systemd":
        if sshSocketStart.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
        elif firewalldStart.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "sshd":
        if sshdSessionClosed.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "sudo":
        if sessionOpenedRoot.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "CROND":
        if sessionOpenedRoot.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "anacron":
        if anacronNormalExit.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "postfix/anvil":
        if postfixStatistics.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    elif entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'] == "su":
        if suSessionClosedGit.match(entry['MESSAGE']):
            pass
    else:
        mailContent.append( 'S %s %s %s: %s' % (
            datetime.ctime(entry['__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP']),
            entry['PRIORITY'],
            entry['SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER'],
            entry['MESSAGE']
        ))

# Send the content in a mail to root
mail = MIMEText('\n'.join(mailContent))
mail['Subject'] = '[example.com] Logs from ' + datetime.ctime(yesterday) + ' to ' + datetime.ctime(datetime.now())
mail['From'] = 'journald@example.com'
mail['To'] = 'root@example.com'
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.send_message(mail)
server.quit()
```